# How can get array of frequency from audio?

Tags: java, android, audio, fft, frequency

Now I can get only array of bytes from audio file. But I need frequency of sound. How I can get it. I'm trying the fft. But after that I get very big numbers and it's not frequency. Of course, I can't to mult to i, because this is Java

```
private static double[] fft(byte[] bytes) {
        double[] fft = new double[bytes.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < bytes.length; k++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < bytes.length; n++) {
                fft[k] += bytes[n] * Math.pow(Math.E, -2 * Math.PI * k * n / bytes.length);
            }
        }
        return fft;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a complex type for your FFT calculations, it will make everything simpler (or at least more readable) and doesn't add a lot of overhead.

I am not a java person, it doesnt seem like JDK has a built in complex type BUT implementations like this exist:
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html

Your FFT could then be something like this (a bit unoptimized pseudo code!):

```
private static Complex[] fft(byte[] bytes) {
        Complex[] fft = new Complex[bytes.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < bytes.length; k++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < bytes.length; n++) {
                Complex temp = new Complex (0,-2 * Math.PI * k * n/bytes.length);
                fft[k] += bytes[n] * Complex.exp(temp);   
            }
        }
        return fft;
    }
```

You can get the magnitudes with something like

```
Complex.abs(fft[k])
```

I would also look at your outer loop (k), this is the size of your FFT and it will currently be the length of the input. This may or may not be what you want, I would suggest looking at signal windowing.

Comment: The `fft` function should return `Complex[]`, and `temp` be constructed with `new Complex(0,-2*Math.PI*k*n/bytes.length)` (the real part should be 0).

Comment: Good catch @SleuthEye.